# Derive the equation of motion for test masses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics

I currently have the topic Newtonian gravity, which is described as a field theory by means of the Poisson equation
$$\Delta \phi = 4\pi G\rho\,.$$
As an assignment I have: derive the equation of motion for test masses. (1 point, short task)

I can do something with the single words, but their combination to this sentence, I don't understand. What should I derive? And from what? Should I derive according to the mass, so $\frac{d}{dm}$? And why? What is the point of that? Where should this lead me. This task confuses me.

Comment: The equation of motion would be the set of differential equations that govern the time evolution of the position of the test particle. Deriving them simply means to apply some method, be that using Newton's laws, a Lagrangian, or the Hamiltonian formalism to arrive at the second order differential equation governing the motion of a particle in the potential.

Comment: Does the $\triangle$ mean the Laplacian operator?  I'm used to seeing it as $\nabla^2$

Comment: Here, "derive" means to generate from some sequence of logical steps, not to take the derivative. So, start with the given information, do some math (this is the hard part), and end with the requested information $-$ the equation of motion for test masses.